# How to refere to the parent of a child instance

Tags: java, inheritance

I am writing a project in Java.
I have a structure where I have instances of objects A, B and C, all of which extend class Parent.

I want to have a list of all objects of type Parent - i.e. I want to store any object of type A, B or C in this list.

I have created a list class with the function

```
private class Item
{
  private Parent parent;

  public void addItem(Parent set){ /* adds set to the list */};
}
```

My original idea was to do something like this:

```
A a = new A(); B b = new B();
addItem(a);
addItem(b);
```

But a and b are not Parents they are A and Bs.

Can someone suggest a way of being able to add instances of As, Bs, Cs... to a list of Parents?

Comment: You need to rephrase your post. The first half of it is contradicting the second half.

Comment: You said that A, B and C extend Parent, which means in a inheritance tree, A, B and C are all subclasses of parent.  Therefore if what you said at the beginning is true, your addItem(a); code will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you mean is how do you polymorph an a,b,c to their parent super type? Well, since they subtype the parent type the add method as you defined it should cast your subtype to parent implicitly.

Otherwise how you explicitly refer to the parent type of a subtype is by using a type cast expression... Which is expressed like this:

```
T_Parent varname = (T_Parent) Name_Subclass;
```